# How to use .add() function to merge two dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

Please use the image attached as reference .

I have two dataframes

df_class_a

with data :

```
Subject maximum minimum
Physics  98      50 
Maths    100     45 
Chem     99      65
```

df_class_b with data

```
Subject maximum minimum
Maths    100     45 
Physics  98      44 
Chem     85      50 
language 88      54
```

and I want to merge them to form a new data frame  say df_add

```
Subject maximum minimum
Maths    200     90 
Physics  196     94 
Chem     184     115 
Language  88     54
```

which will be sum of the dataframes but both of them do not have same rows of data. How can I do it using .add functionality in pandas.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
m = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Subject', how='outer')
m['maximum'] = m[['maximum_x', 'maximum_y']].sum(axis=1)
m['minimum'] = m[['minimum_x', 'minimum_y']].sum(axis=1)

print(m[['Subject', 'maximum', 'minimum']])
```

Prints:

```
    Subject  maximum  minimum
0     Maths    200.0     90.0
1   Physics    196.0     94.0
2      Chem    184.0    115.0
3  language     88.0     54.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Subject` to index in both `DataFrames` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `fill_value=0)`:

```
df = df_class_a.set_index('Subject').add(df_class_b.set_index('Subject'), fill_value=0)
print (df)
          maximum  minimum
Subject                   
Chem        184.0    115.0
Maths       200.0     90.0
Physics     196.0     94.0
language     88.0     54.0
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_class_a, df_class_b]).groupby('Subject', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
    Subject  maximum  minimum
0      Chem      184      115
1     Maths      200       90
2   Physics      196       94
3  language       88       54
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df_add = pd.DataFrame({
'Subject': df_class_a['Subject'],
'Maximum': df_class_a['Maximum']+df_class_b['Maximum'],
'Minimum': df_class_a['Minimum']+df_class_b['Minimum']
})
```

Comment: I chnage data in question for see, why your solution is bad.